# Cabal install command Gives error

Tags: haskell, cabal

I can't understand why it just dosen't work. My question is what might have gone wrong i have created the ~/.bash_profile and tried to add the PATH given by the haskell webpage.

When i preform cabal install i get this output:

```
Marcuss-MacBook-Pro:~ marcuslagerstedt$ cabal install
cabal: Error reading local package.
Couldn't find .cabal file in: .
Marcuss-MacBook-Pro:~ marcuslagerstedt$
```

I hope i did a correct question. 
But i really need help aswell.

Comment: Why are you including the string `<br />`?  That's just some junk HTML tags and not part of any command.

Comment: If you execute `cabal install` without specifying the name of a package then it assumes your local directory contains a package and the matching `packagename.cabal` file.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Wanted to run cabal update cabal install, maybe i got the wrong idea ? 
I'm about to install agda to atom and it dosen't work completly so i went back to check that i got everything installed and updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to install a particular package, namely `agda`.  The command `cabal install` takes either the name of a package or assumes you are installing some package in the local directory.  You are hitting this second case.

To install agda try:

```
cabal update
cabal install agda
```

Comment: this work but i had to use the uninstall haskell first (i ran the uninstall.hs file)